# Daily maximum and bounty

Tags: discussion

It shows that I've reached my maximum today, but only because of a bounty.  I thought bounties did not apply to the maximum?  This is community wiki as I'm sure the answer is out there somewhere and I can't find it...

**EDIT**
Because I received a huge bounty today, any other points coming in, even though I'm at less than 200 for normal voting, is basically thrown aside.  I think that bounties should either count or they shouldn't.  This wishy washy stuff makes things difficult.

Comment: -1 for random usage of community wiki

Comment: +1s all around because it makes no difference ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: This changed in late March 2010. Bounties and accepted answers no longer contribute to the rep cap at all.

---

(Old rules)

Bounties are not *bound* by the limit, but they *contribute* to the limit.

So if you get 100 point bounty after getting to (say) 215, you go to 315.

If you get 100 point bounty after getting to 50, you go to 150 - and the rep limit will still hit at 200, not 300.

Comment: Out of curiosity--what's the best rep day you've ever had? I'm sure you've had a multi-bounty day, eh?

Comment: @Eric: I don't get very many bounties actually. Typically if I know an answer, I'll post it well before a bounty is placed. I think my best is 583 in a day - that included 300 bounty, but it was right at the start of the day. I *thought* I'd got 1000 over the course of two days, but it looks like some questions have been deleted since then... it's now just 983.

Comment: I've been disillusioned by your apparent inability to break 4 digits in 2 days. I'm going to have to shift all my adoration to Marc Gravell.

Comment: This is no longer true

Comment: @Downvoter: You're right. Will edit.

Answer (score 4):

Bounties are not subject to the cap if you get them *after* the cap. I got my 300 pointer after hitting the cap today, so I had a 500 rep day. It's a good day.

Answer (score 4):

My fault, I was going to award it yesterday at 6:59 PM EST but I was at a golf outing that was delayed due to rain. I at least waited until the last few minutes before awarding it.

The true problem is that we have to play these games in order to award people as I believe they were originally intended by the system.

I will continue to upvote any suggestions that the **REPUTATION CAP SHOULD ONLY APPLY TO VOTES**. This would not only be easier to implement, but would be more fair... and during a recalc it would greatly increase some users' points that have contributed above and beyond once they hit the cap.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Do you have that as a feature request somewhere on meta?

Comment: I suggested something similar here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/should-the-rep-recalc-award-accepted-answer-and-bounty-points-at-the-end-of-the - but it was brought up by tvanfosson that the real problem is what I suggested in this answer. I'm *sure* this has been brought up before, I'll have to search a bit. If I can't find it I will propose it

Comment: Alright, requested here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/only-apply-the-rep-cap-to-score-from-votes

Comment: Thanks. I voted that request and Cletus' answer.