# Reputation Cap and Simple Math - Where are my points?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

Simple math is perplexing me. Today I earned 580 points on SO. 550 were from answering a bounty and 30 were from upvotes. According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> ...bounty awards, like all accepted
>   answers, are immune to the daily
>   reputation cap...

I've received at least 5 more upvotes since then on a different posting, but no points. Is something wrong with the system? Have I misunderstood basic addition and subtraction here?

(p.s. I've searched for an answer on mSO and haven't found one, that's why I'm asking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bounty is immune to the daily reputation cap, *after* the cap has already been hit.

So in your case, you earned 30 points, got the 550 from the bounty which pushed you to the cap, and now you won't earn any additional reputation from normal upvotes.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/only-apply-the-rep-cap-to-score-from-votes) for more details.

Comment: oh man, if I'd known that I would have just not done anything on the site until a new day had come. sucks.

Comment: @Otaku: surely you answer questions for other motivations than the incrementing of an arbitrary integer counter?

Comment: @Otaku - also the reason why I encourage people to accept their answers (bounty or otherwise) at the end of the stackoverflow day, so the cap isn't stunted prematurely.

Comment: @Ether - nope. that's all I do it for. Why else would I do it? I "earn" points so that I can later offer up bounties for tough questions that I need help with.

Comment: @Otaku - I wouldn't worry about having rep to offer up bounties. I've asked plenty of questions, and have never once needed to offer a bounty to get a decent answer.

Comment: that's one strategy. not one that I think will work forever based on the nature of the questions though. isn't why there are bounties to begin with? paid advertising, per se, for a week to float an issue in front of point hungry people?